# In Angular event calling issue in ngSelect's options

Tags: html, angular, typescript

hiii, I am using ngSelect but i have one issue which i am facing like, whenever user hover on any option of ngSelection
on that hover i want to call event which created in my ts file and i am using angular 13 how to do that or is it
possible?

```
      `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 col-12 custom-select">
        <div class="form-group form-focus select-focus">
          <ng-select [(ngModel)]="employeeCode" (change)="onLeaveFilterChange()" [allowClear]="false"
            [placeholder]="'-- Select --'" dropdownPosition="bottom" class="form-control">
            <ng-option [value]="'null'">-- Select --</ng-option>
            <ng-option *ngFor="let data of totalLeavedEmployeeList" [value]="data.empCode">
              {{ data?.empCode }} - {{ data?.empName }}
            </ng-option>
          </ng-select>
          <label class="focus-label">Employee</label>
        </div>
      </div>`
```

I am expecting like on hover function would be call, which will in my ts file?

Comment: Check out the mouseover event.
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-how-to-use-angular-mouseenter-event